# Java reports Mac OS 12 as 11.2

Tags: java, macos

We are using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11, and have found that on Mac OS 12, System.getProperty("os.version") returns 11.2.

I've been unable to find any mention of this anywhere, which makes me suspect that SOMEHOW our application is doing something weird, but I don't know of any way we could cause this.

Comment: Using Oracle Java 16.0.2, it reports MacOS 12.3.1 as 11.3, so either it's an issue with MacOS or a baseline issue with Java implementation overall

Comment: My openjdk 18.0.1 reports Mac OS 12.3.1 as 12.3.1